# How to replace ../ from the path using Python and Django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I need to replace the up directory path like `../` from the file path using Python. Here is my code:

```
filepath=nest/../../upload/

        or

 filepath = ../../../../upload/
```

Here I need to remove those `../` from that file path using Python.

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.realpath` can do that for you

For example, if I try to resolve my home dir with some up directory references, I get the root of my fs:

```
>>> os.path.realpath("/home/fernando/../../")
>>> '/'
```

Consider that `os.path.realpath` will also resolve symlinks for you, and if you don't want that, you might want to check `os.path.abspath`